# JMeter - rerun failed step without rerunning the entire test

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

Is there a mechanism/workaround in JMeter to rerun any failed step from a test without having to rerun the entire thread/test?

I have seen the usage of the If controller but that would require If controllers at any step and duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) and the following reference code:

```
if (!SampleResult.isSuccessful()) {
    SampleResult = ctx.getCurrentSampler().sample(null);
}
```

The above code will re-execute failed sampler one more time. Explanations:

- `SampleResult` - an instance of [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class, provides read/write access to current sampler result
- `ctx` - shorthand to [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class

See above classes JavaDoc for available methods and fields and [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean mechanism to do what you want.

The code shown by Dmitri is a hack and may have consequences in different fields:

- An assertion is made to check response not to do an action so you expose yourself to future problems
- Re-running a request is not realistic and should be limited to where it is feasable. For example POST usually modify server state and you cannot replay them
- You are not really simulating load on application and possibly introducing issues in application by doing so